# Is it valid to write $\sin(x+iy)=\sin (x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I'm asked to sketch the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}:\sin z$ is a real number $\}$

Here's what I did:

$$
\sin(x + iy) = \sin(x) \cos(iy) + \cos(x) \sin(iy)
$$

But since we only want the real part, then this is equal $\cos x + \sin x$. Is this valid?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure if this identity would apply in the complex case

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You may further use $\cos(iy)=\cosh y$ and $\sin(iy)=i\sinh y$:

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: answer?

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about real part: it *does not* mean just cross out any expression containing an $i$.  If you have $a+ib$, where $a,b$ are real numbers, then the real part is $a$.  But your above expression is not in the form $a+ib$.

Comment: @David yes I thought it meant to get the real portion which was wrong. So then this would be true if $y=0$? Or is there more solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**.  Continuing what you did, and using the comment from Pedro Tamaroff,
$$\sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y\ .$$
But now read your question carefully: you are not asked for the real part of $\sin z$, but for the values of $z$ such that $\sin z$ is real.  So, what can you say about $x$ and $y$ if the above expression is a real number?

Comment: is $y=0$ one of them?

Comment: I'm thinking this would be the case if $y=0$

Comment: That's correct but can you find other solutions too?

Comment: $x=y=\pi n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Check by substituting back and carefully evaluating to see if you get a real number.

Comment: I'm of the firm belief $x=\pi n$ and $y=0$

Comment: What about $x=\pi/2$ and $y=12345.6789$?

Comment: lol why couldn't I think of that? Anyways I know the general idea now. I want to know when $\sin x \cos hy=0$ and $i \cos x \sin hy=0$. That's one way to think about it right?

Comment: Not exactly - for $\sin z$ to be real you need $\cos x\sinh y$ to be zero but it doesn't matter what the other one is.